# How to Krita - Creating user defined pixel brushes to match Ctrl+Paint

Tags: brush, krita

I am new to Krita and have read through a number of documentations on setting up pixel brushes.  I am trying to match the brush and eraser behavior as shown in this tutorial https://www.ctrlpaint.com/digital-painting-101/brusheraser (shown beginning at 1:00 to 2:30).

I believe I got relatively close to what he terms the hard round brush by setting the diameter to 25, checking anti-aliasing, checking auto and setting spacing to 0.3.  Then unchecking size and shaping the curve for flow to gently rise to a short plateau in the middle and again gently rise to 100% in the top right corner.  I am sure something could be done better and maybe Photoshop's brush engine is sufficiently different that it would be difficult to match, I have my doubts though but I have no experience with Photoshop.  These settings seem to match the hard pressure behavior well but it really doesn't match the behavior at the initial start and a few of the softer edges that occur during the video.

Also I cannot figure out how to match what he terms the soft round brush.  Is it just a matter of getting the curve for a soft mask type just right?

I understand getting them to be perfectly the same is rather unnecessary in order to follow his tutorials.  My posting this question has more to do with my desire to actually know how to go about designing brushes to get the desired results.  Here the goal was to match Ctrl+Paint tutorial brushes and I find I do not know how to reach that goal.  It's a skill that will be important later on I am sure.

Answer (score 1):

*The video example Ctrl+Paint show by you into the range of time* is:

- a basic use of shortkeys used with this features: Brush tool (B) and Eraser tool (E).

Krita has these features and you can create your own brush sets and is more advanced than CtrlPaint.